# html5 audio won't play 14.04

Tags: sound, html5

I have been unable to hear anything in any html5 player, and it started today. My sound card works fine, and it even says that Youtube or some other HTML5 player is playing audio, but I cannot hear it. I've tried clearing the cache, restarting Chrome, restarting the computer, running updates, and re-installing Chrome. I also get the same result when I try this with Chromium. Any ideas?

Comment: Do your local music player make any sound? I mean if you tested the sound using other than web

Comment: What desktop environment do you use?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

it's just html5 audio for me, chrome can play sound from flash videos but html videos freeze, using pulse audio volume control to change the sound to, for example, HDMI output, the video starts playing (but I cannot hear sound) switch back, and video pauses. Like I say though, other, non html5 sound via the browser works. Firefox also has the same issue.

I'm using Gnome.